# PetFinder API with React App - Can't resolve 401 error

Tags: reactjs, api, petfinder

I am using the PetFinder API, and keep running into a 401 error. I cannot figure out a solution - Any help is appreciated

```
    const [pets, setPets] = useState([]);
  const url = "https://api.petfinder.com/v2/animals";

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        Authorization: `"Bearer: ${process.env.REACT_APP_access_token}"`,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPets(data);
        console.log(pets);
      });
  }, [pets]);
```

I am also getting an 'unexpected end of input' error I cannot track down

```
PetCard.js:8          GET https://api.petfinder.com/v2/animals net::ERR_ABORTED 401
(anonymous) @ PetCard.js:8
c
PetCard.js:8 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at PetCard.js:8:1)
    at PetCard.js:8:1
```

Comment: You included an unnecessary colon in your authorization string. Remove the `:` after `Bearer`: `"Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_access_token}"`.

Comment: I will take a look at it later - Thank you for catching that!

Comment: Turns out it is not pulling in my key from the env file.. and I took out the no-cors as it was not useful and not the right way to fix it